# Sent BTC to BCH address by accident

Tags: blockchain, address, funds

Posted elsewhere but I'll paste here too: I just tried to transfer BTC from Exodus to Coinbase but accidentally used the BCH address on coinbase and now I've lost all my funds. Any one got any sort of help whatsoever??? I'm an idiot I know and i'm freaking out

Comment: So you have BCH now but no BTC on Coinbase? Also, out of interest, what was the reason for transferring from Exodus to Coinbase? I am sorry - I am not sure if you can resolve your issue. You would have to sell BCH and buy BTC on Coinbase / GDAX, I assume.